# PHP поиск элемента в двумерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

```
$arr = array(
   array('a' => 2, 'b' => 15),
   array('a' => 3, 'b' => 15),
   array('a' => 4, 'b' => 2),
   array('a' => 8, 'b' => 3),
   array('a' => 15, 'b' => 1),
);
```

Есть переменная $a со значением 5 или 3. Или же есть переменная $b с каким-то значением.

Как узнать без перебора в цикле, т.е. без сторонних функций, совпадает ли значение переменной $a с любым элементом массива $arr по полю 'a'. Тоже самое с переменной $b? Что-то типа in_array() или array_search().

Comment: А по вашему in_array и array_search перебора не делают?

Comment: как-то так ` in_array($a, array_column($array, 'a')) `

Comment: `т.е. без сторонних функций` - в смысле вообще без встроенных функций php и без циклов? никак ..... или для вас сторонняя функция - это только цикл? О_о

Comment: @splash58 оформите ответом, плюсануть хочется. Век живи, век учись :)

Comment: @rjhdby оформил, но непонятно, это ли надо автору вопроса

Comment: "Сторонние функции" - это не встроенные. Просто зачем "придумывать велосипед". Хочу извинится за свою лень. Можно было просто пересмотреть весь списор функц. PHP для работы с массивами. Огромное спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра лучше тогда никогда не писать словосочетание "сторонние функции" если имеется банальный стандартный цикл

Comment: ок, извините, что ввел Вас в недоразумение этим словосочетанием.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [array_column](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php), чтобы получить массив значений нужной колонки, например

```
$a = 3;

if(in_array($a, array_column($arr, 'a'))) {
   echo 'yes'; 
}
```

Comment: На самом деле это довольно часто возникающая задача, так что если не автору вопроса, так кому еще поможет. Я вот, например, не знал о такой полезной функции, а в свое время очень помогла бы :)

Comment: @rjhdby если не ошибаюсь, array_column идёт в пхп с версии 5.5

Comment: @Эдуард, да. а с 7-ки можно массив объектов в качестве аргумента

Comment: @splash58 я это к тому, что у тс ваш код вполне может не запуститься.

Comment: @Эдуард ну вот кто-то о ней знает, а кто-то упустил. В PHP много функций

Comment: вот облом. У меня на денвере PHP Version 5.3.13

Comment: обновил PHP до 5.6.8 на денвере, все заработало. Кстати, если кто не знает как обновить версию PHP на денвере, пишите, с радостью объясню.

Comment: мне кажется, это совсем несложно. но предложение хорошее :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант для PHP <= 5.4

```
$arr = array(
   array('a' => 2, 'b' => 15),
   array('a' => 3, 'b' => 15),
   array('a' => 4, 'b' => 2),
   array('a' => 8, 'b' => 3),
   array('a' => 15, 'b' => 1),
);
// Искомое значчение
$srch = 15;

array_filter($arr, function($a) use (&$int, $srch) {
    return (array_search($srch, $a)) ? ++$int : false;
});
// Количество совпадений
echo ($int ? $int : 0);// 3
```

Comment: А в четверке работать не будет ;)
Ну и нужно было раздельно по полям, а не для всего сразу

Comment: @rjhdby ну четвёркой наверное уже очень мало кто пользуется, а на счёт полей я не понял, уточните, плиз.

Comment: Автору нужно единовременно по одной колонке искать, а у вас по всему вложенному массиву. А про четверку это я ёрничаю, но по совести и 5.5 уже мало где найдешь, про более младшие и говорить нечего.